# Is there a function that will allow me to populate cell with text based on range of value in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to display set based on a range of %values.  Here's the scenario:

Column F contains a %value.  I want to populate Column G with text based on column F value

If column F value is exactly 0%, Column G text is On Track

If Column F value is less than 0%, Column G text is Below Forecast

If Column F value is greater than 0%, Column G text is Exceed Forecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways, I prefer CHOOSE/MATCH:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(F2,{-1E+99,0,0.0001}),"Below Forecast","On Track","Exceed Forecast")
```

the MATCH will return 1,2, or 3 depending on where the value in F2 lands in the array of values.  Choose will then return the correct string depending on the value from the MATCH.

Answer (score 1):

I Like Scott's solution, but you can use IF() as well:

```
=IF(F1<0,"Below Forecast",IF(F1=0,"On Track","Exceed Forecast"))
```

See

[image]

Comment: Ha, same answer, same time! I'll delete mine (yours has a fancy screenshot :))

Comment: @JvdV Cheers mate, much appreciated.